# Display button on UICollectionViewCell after UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a Cell from a CollectionView and I want to display a button from that (and all the others) cells after a long touch happens. Here's my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: CellController = collection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellController

        cell.exitButton.hidden = true

        return cell
    }
```

I want to set to false the `cell.exitButton.hidden` after the touch happen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a bool variable in the collectionView's class scope. When you detect the long press, modify the bool variable. In this example, I'll declare it as `var exitButtonHidden = true`.

Change your implementation of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, such that it modifies `cell.exitButton.hidden = true` to `cell.exitButton.hidden = exitButtonHidden`.

Now, you need to do is call `reloadData` on the collectionView whenever you detect the long press so that the collectionView gets a chance to refresh all the cells again.